prove a function is not Lebesgue integrable

Let $ f$ be a function defined on the interval $[a, b]$, and there
exist constants $ M > 0 $ and $ \alpha \geq 1 $ such that
$$ |f(x)| \geq \dfrac{M}{|x - x_0|^\alpha} $$
for some $ a < x_0 < b $, for almost all $ x \in \mathbb{R} $. Then $
 f $ is not Lebesgue integrable.

My idea is to prove that $\dfrac{M}{|x - x_0|^\alpha}$ is not Lebesgue integrable. Since then, $|f|$ is not Lesbegue integrable and we already know that $|f|$ is L-integrable $\iff f$ is L-integrable, hence $f$ is not L-integrable.
But currently, I don't know how to prove $\dfrac{M}{|x - x_0|^\alpha}$ is not Lebesgue integrable (Also, I was hinted to use Dominated convergence theorem). Any help I would be very grateful!

Integrate from $x_0-1$ to $x_0+1$.

@geetha290krm I don't get your idea much. Could you write down in the answering section down below so that I can understand better? ^^

Hint: for what values of $α$ is $\int_0^1 t^α \mathrm{d}t$ finite?

@JeanAbouSamra $a>-1$. So...?

could anyone explain @geetha290krm idea or have any idea to solve this problem?

Just integrate $\frac{M}{|x-x_0|^\alpha}$ from $x_0$ to $x_0+1$ and make a change of variables $t=x-x_0$. Then as you wrote yourself the fact that $\alpha \ge 1$ is of relevance. Note: The integral $\int_0^1 t^a dt$ is also infinite for $a=-1$.

Using the given inequality,
$$\int_a^b \lvert f(x)\rvert\,\mathrm{d}x\geq M\int_a^b\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\lvert x-x_0\rvert^\alpha}\geq M\int_{x_0}^{x_0+\varepsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\lvert x-x_0\rvert^\alpha}\geq M\int_{x_0}^{x_0+\varepsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x-x_0}=M\int_0^\varepsilon\frac{\mathrm{d}\xi}{\xi}=M\lim_{\delta\downarrow0}\left(\ln(\varepsilon)-\ln\left(\delta\right)\right)=\infty,$$
where $\varepsilon>0$ is just some sufficiently small number, and the limit at the end can be justified with the monotone convergence theorem, so $\int_a^b\lvert f(x)\rvert\,\mathrm{d}x=\infty$, meaning that $f\notin L^1([a,b])$.
